# Bulk extract with Authenticated Connector (import.io)

Tags: api, extract, bulk, connector, import.io

I am new to import.io and this forum.

I am trying to extract information from a target database where I have to run a query with an input. With help of the support, I successfully created the authenticated connector. With multiple inputs that have to be manually entered in the UI, it fetches the data properly.

The problem is I have more than 10,000 inputs to run, so it has to be in a form of bulk extraction. import.io support told me that they do not have this feature within their UI and suggested to use their API posted in here: http://api.docs.import.io/#!/Query_Methods/queryPost.

Could anyone walk me through to make a use of this? I just need a working script that takes multiple string lines as inputs and run the connector that I built and post the result. I am not very familiar with this kind of technology but I am very willing to learn.

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I would be happy to walk you through a bit of an into. It will be a bit basic though since I don't know your specific use case.

Yes, support was correct. You will need to use the POST query in order to pass your authentication credentials as inputs.

[image]

I will break down this query by steps. Essentially, our API docs are just a simple UI to pass through your credentials, then you can generate a query API.

ID - This is the GUID of your connector. This information can be found at the end of the URL, like this: https://import.io/data/mine/?tag=CONNECTOR&id=33f4e828-25ce-40c4-948c-9b734c70d1ab

Query - This is where you will put the inputs from your connector in order to execute. Be sure to keep this in structured JSON or it will bring back errors when you are querying.

Once you have successfully entered that information you will query the API.

[image]

This will give you the request URL that you need to query the API.

If you have anymore questions, just let me know.

Thanks,
Meg